# Убрать вложеность папки в URL битрикс

Tags: битрикс

Хочу сделать на сайте больше 500 страниц SEO. Страницы в битрикс создаю через публичную часть - СОЗДАТЬ РАЗДЕЛ (создается страница и папка в файловой системе).
В коде создается папка с названием раздела и ЧПУ выглядит так https://Домен/название раздела/. - Тут все верно

Для того чтоб не создавать кашу в файлах проекта я хочу все сео страницы собрать в подпапку SEO, но перенося созданные разделы на сайте они становятся доступны по URL
https://Домен/seo/название раздела/.

Как мне убрать промежуточную папку /SEO/ с урл, чтоб все разделы которые буду делать для сео, в коде находились в соответствующей папке, а URL был без вложенной папки, то есть https://Домен/название раздела/

Подскажите кто сталкивался с данной задачкой.

Comment: 1. Попробуй сделать физическую папку /seo/, доступ к которой закрыт.

Comment: 2. Для сео страниц укажи, что они принадлежат одновременно двум разделам: "seo/название раздела" и "название раздела"

Comment: Виктор, а как это сделать? Мне важно из урла убрать папку в которой все вкладываю. Сеошник говорит это очень важно, чтоб был 1 уровня урл.

Comment: На закладке "Разделы" можно указать несколько разделов для элемента - кликаешь мышкой, зажав кнопку Ctrl.

Comment: Проблема в том что я работаю с статическими страницами (папки которые создаются в корне сайта на хосте) и там нет элементов и ЧПУ строится от корня сайта по вложенности.

Comment: Если создать физическую папку /seo/, то ЧПУ не будет работать для адресов вида "/seo/название раздела". ЧПУ работает через urlrewrite, а urlrewrite вызывается только при отсутствии физической папки. Если в эту папку поместить .htaccess с текстом "Deny from all", то мы запретим к ней доступ. То есть папка seo физически будет на сервере, но её не будет на сайте.

Answer (score 0):

через htaccess надо подменять адрес, примерно так:

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/seo/.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://site.ru/seo/$1 [L]

- но так у вас все запросы будут уходить в папку seo.

Но вообще плодить файлы и папки плохая идея. Используйте инфоблок, настройте ЧПУ, редактируйте контент через админку